# How do I find the elements inside a list using another list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have a long expression which contains many `x`. I want to see where all the x are so I do `pos=Position[expr, x, Infinity]` and I find something like

```
{{1, 5, 1, 1}, {1, 5, 1, 2}, {1, 6, 1, 1}, {1, 8, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 8, 1, 3, 2, 1, 
  2, 2, 1}, {1, 8, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 8, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {1,
   10, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 10, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
  1}, {1, 10, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 10, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2,
   3, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 
  2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1}}
```

I want to see which types of expressions contain an x, for example, the x could be inside (x-y)^2 or y/x or whatever. So I do `posit = Drop[#, -1] & /@ pos` and I have my list with all the positions of the expressions containing and "x". This is fine. If I type `expr[[1,5,1]]` or `expr[[{1},{5},{1}]]` I can do that by hand. But I don't want to do that for every case in posit, I want to do something like

`Table[expr[[posit[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[posit]}]` and see a table with all the cases that contain x.

But if do this what I am doing is `expr[[{1,5,1}]]` and Mathematica doesn't show the position `[[1,5,1]]` of `expr` but rather the position 1, the position 5 and the position 1 again of the whole `expr`.

How do I remove the brackets of `{1,5,1}` so I can have `expr[[1,5,1]]` by taking all the elements in the list `posit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expr = {Nest[foo, x/y, 5], 2, x^2 + y, 3 x, 1/x + y, 5}
```

> ```
> {foo[foo[foo[foo[foo[x/y]]]]], 2, x^2 + y, 3 x, 1/x + y, 5}
> ```

```
pos = Position[expr, x, Infinity]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
posit = Drop[pos, None, -1]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 1}, {4}, {5, 1}}
> ```

You can get the desired result in several ways:

```
Table[expr[[Sequence @@ posit[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[posit]}] (* or *)

Table[expr[[Sequence @@ i]], {i, posit}] (* or *)

expr[[##]] & @@@ posit (* or *)

Extract[expr, posit]
```

all give

> ```
>  {x/y, x^2, 3 x, 1/x}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to get the desired result in a single step:

```
Cases[expr, _[___, x, ___], All]
```

> ```
>  {x/y, x^2, 3 x, 1/x}
> ```